# Migrating from one server to another - linebreaks in HTML

Tags: import, migration, server-migration, database-migrations

I'm migrating an EE (2.10.1) installation from one server to another. The CP seems ok, but all of the templates show linebreaks as \n, effectively breaking the site. The SQL import / export appeared to work fine. I guess this is some kind of character set issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I can manually copy template contents from the old site and paste it into the new (does seem to work), but will there be other symptoms caused by the issue that I haven't seen?

**What I see in e.g. the offline template:**

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
\n\n
System Offline

\n\n
This site is currently offline

\n\n
\n\n\n\n
```

**Migrating from:**

Database server

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.52-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
Protocol version: 10
User: loft_user@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
 nginx/1.9.2
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 5.6.14
```

phpMyAdmin

```
Version information: 4.6.5.1
```

**Migrating to:**

Database server

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.53 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: cl31-intoloft@10.0.44.138
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: 731e5b87ba42146a687c29995d2dfd8b4e40b325 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
```

phpMyAdmin

```
Version information: 4.0.10.18
```

Comment: I had this happen not long ago, I dropped the tables and reimported and everything looked fine.  It was really odd and I didn't change anything on my reimport.

Comment: I've tried that a few times with no luck

Comment: Hmm, another thing I just thought about. My original export like yours was from phpMyAdmin, but I exported the second time as a SQL Dump (not from phpMyAdmin).  I dropped the old tables, then reimported back into phpMyAdmin with the dump, and that's when it sorted itself out.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts but I've just figured it out - simple fix in the end. I did a find and replace in the SQL file, replacing \\n with \n

Comment: Glad you fixed it! I've had odd troubles recently with phpMyAdmin and character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix in the end. I performed a find and replace in the SQL file - replacing "\n" with "\n". (No quotes)